# Difference between lì and là

Tags: difference, vocabulary, adverbs

I have translated "there" into Italian language. There are "lì" and "là".

I am studying the difference between them.

Hypothesis: these two words are used to refer to a place far from the person that is speaking. "Lì" means closer than "là" ("lì" - there e.g. in the same room, "là" - there e.g. in a different country).

Question: To refer to a person in a different city, which one should I use?

Thank you.

Comment: *Lì*, *là*, *laggiù*, *lassù*, *da quelle parti*... (not even mentioning *costì* or *ci* and other possible translations in different contexts) and the like. You cannot possibly learn a language word by word. Have you a precise sentence in mind? You should read a lot of Italian texts, and then you'll get the hang of such almost-synonyms.

Comment: What do you mean by “I have translated”? Looked up in a dictionary? Asked a friend? Made a guess based on something you have read? Been inspired by the Holy Ghost?

Comment: I agree with @DaG: it's not a good approach to learn a new language trying to translate every single word you know in English.

Comment: @DaG I used a dictionary

Comment: @cornejo What is your level of proficiency in Italian? As a rule of thumb I wouldn't worry about shades of meaning until you are able to ask questions in Italian on this site and understand the answers

Comment: More or less, *lì* is “near” and *là* is “far” with respect to who's hearing.

Comment: Consider _questo_, _codesto_ and  _quello_. Similarly, _qua_, _lì_, and _là_.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, they are both really similar. There isn't much difference except for some nuance.

"Lì" usually refers to something closer than "là", at the same time, "lì" is also describing a more specific place than "là".

The use of "qua" and "là" is for spatial genericity. for example, you would use "qua e là" for something here and there or all over the place, but you wouldn't say "qui e lì" as that would mean exactly in this and that spot.

You would apply the same difference to "quì" and "qua".

I'd say that to refer to someone in a different city you can safely use "là", if you need to refer to that specific city in contract with the region or an area, then "lì" might be better suited.

Answer (score 1):

While they could be used interchangeably you are almost right to say they *là* is farther than *lì*. However when it comes to colloquial Italian those differences are circumstantial. When you are pointing at something out of your reach (even in the same room) both are acceptable for example. When you are referring to a different country as you said *là* is more commonly used.

I'd say, as a rule of thumb, that you should consider *là* as an abbreviation or alternative of *laggiù*.

Ref: http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/L/la.php

Comment: I was agreeing with you until the last paragraph. *Là* is not an abbreviation of *laggiù* and I really do not perceive a difference between *là* and *lì*, while *laggiù* does have a connotation of distance.

Comment: Laggiù as in "laggiù in Sicilia..." Or "laggiù in Alaska" means a place that is far away from the speaker but is close to either the person he is speaking to or they are speaking about. So of course it has a connotation of distance. It can be translate as "down there".

Comment: I am well aware of the meaning and etymology of *laggiù*. Sorry if I expressed myself unclearly, what I meant is that I perceive *là* and *lì* as interchangeable (and dictionaries seem to mostly agree with me on this), while *laggiù* has a slightly different meaning, with a stronger emphasis on the distance and so I disagree with (the last paragraph of) your answer.

Comment: Edited my answer with reference to Italian dictionary.